# Can't edit/delete comments outside of main site

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, android-app

In the Android app, tapping on my own comments should offer me a menu with the option to edit or delete the comment. (The edit option persists after 5 minutes, which it shouldn't, but that's something else.)

This menu only works for me on my main site, the Judaism site. On other sites, like Meta.SO or SU, I get the option to vote up (which doesn't work).

This is because it does a simple check for my main site's userid (883). This is obviously different on different sites. However, *it does give me the option to edit or delete on every site's user 883*.

I didn't try. Maybe I should. You know. For science.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fixed in the next update, thanks!