# I can't edit any of my own posts on meta sites in the Android app

Tags: bug, status-completed, edits, android-app, per-site-meta

On site metas, I can't edit my own questions, answers, or comments. Tapping on a question or a comment brings up the same dialog I get for other users posts, while answers don't give me a dialog at all. The only exception is for Meta.SO, where I *can* edit my posts.

Perhaps there are lingering issues from here? [Can't edit/delete comments outside of main site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/195127/cant-edit-delete-comments-outside-of-main-site)

Comment: Update: [meta-tag:status-completed]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was fixed in a previous build but we missed updating the bug, sorry about that!